# Docker layer cache miss on project level when trying to deploy default Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Background: I am building a cloud function using python to take a .csv uploaded to our bucket and upload its rows as entities into Datastore.

When trying to deploy the Python function, I got an error where the function would fail to deploy due to the following error code:

```
Build failed: {
  "cacheStats": [{
    "status": "MISS", 
    "hash": "SOME HASH", 
    "type": "docker_layer_cache",
    "level": "global"
    }, {
    "status": "MISS", 
    "hash": "SOME HASH",
    "type": "docker_layer_cache",
    "level": "project"
    }
  ]
}
```

To try to diagnose the problem, I attempted deploying a template Python function, and got the same error. (Code included below just in case)

```
def hello_world(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request.args and 'message' in request.args:
        return request.args.get('message')
    elif request_json and 'message' in request_json:
        return request_json['message']
    else:
        return f'Hello World!'
```

From my understanding of the error, it implies that there is an issue with the hashing to my project specifically, but it is not clear to me how to fix this, or what resulted in this error occurring.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting has no information about an error of this type, and other errors that I have seen similar to this error are due to situations such as the entry function parameters being incorrect, which is not the case here.

Cloud functions are running as normal according to google (https://status.cloud.google.com/).

***Is this a genuine problem on google's end? Or is there some setting that I am not aware of that would have caused this issue?***

Update: Node.js functions are working fine, python functions still do not work.  In addition, Go functions result in an error where the logs fail on build step #5 due to `Token exchange failed for project: 'project-id'`

Comment: I had a similar issue, and aparently is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/154260223) that was mainly happening with the python envirornment and nodejs8.

What the Google Team asked there to the people who is still experiencing the issue is to [contact support](https://console.cloud.google.com//support) as they can inspect the specific case and assist you.

Comment: From what I am seeing, the known issue has to do with cache hit on the project but miss on the global level.  My error involves a miss on both global and project levels.  Doing further work to attempt to find other related errors in the issue tracker.